# How to handle 'popout/popup' of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement a 'popout' feature for my react app which uses video.js for streaming services.

Essentially , the below component renders a video stream on the site.

```
              <Player
                ready={this.props.ready}
                stream={stream}
                streamName={ streamName }
                ownStream={this.props.ownStream}
                ref={`player-${stream.id}`}
                unmount={this.props.unmount}
                isSignedIn={this.props.isSignedIn}
                dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
                />
```

On clicking the popout icon , I would like to have only the video (and not any other components on the page) open in a new window.

So i implemented the below in my routes file

```
<Route path="/watch/popout_stream/:streamId" component={StreamPopout} />
```

So now i have a separate page only for rendering the player.

But there doesnt seem to be a way for me to pass all my props from the existing window to the new component (since its on a different window - my redux state is also refreshed).

Is there any way i can pass props to a new component in a completely new window?

Thanks

Comment: I think that this is discussed [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3080). The solution seems to be related with using `window.open` and sending the state with `postMessage` to the new window.

Comment: @CésarLandesa - Thanks :) i'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

You could

- Use window.open (your-domian-url,, '_blank', options={})
- Remove the root dom node  which acts as the target for your react app, why ? You have the css etc in the headers . A problem with other approaches is that its hard to add styles to a popout window.
- Create a div to load your component, e.g. let myDiv =  myWindow.document.createElement('div') and give it an id
- Use React.render and if you need to pass some props in use cloneElement, e.g. render(myComponent, myDiv.id)
- 5.Use post Message to communicate between the windows (best to give popout windows a unique id and store that in the state of the app for
  security - that is only allow registered popout windows to
  communicate with the 'main' application
  Hope that's useful